# BeanFactoryAware VS. @Autowired - is autowiring BeanFactory a bad idea?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Or, in a different way - what is better, to use autowiring:

```
@Autowired
private BeanFactory beanFactory;
```

or implement `BeanFactoryAware`:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfigurationClass implements BeanFactoryAware {

    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(final BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }
}
```

Is there any difference at all (besides the phase when a BeanFactory instance will be set)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the following situation: 
You have two BeanFactorys in a Context and one of the BeanFactorys has the [@Primary](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html)-annotation.

And assuming the second BeanFactory (not having the [@Primary](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html)-annotation) creates the instance of your class.

In this situation you will have the difference:

Wherat the first kind would @Autowire the [@Primary](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html)-annotated BeanFactory the second kind would wire what is the BeanFactory that creates the Instance.

Comment: Peter, thanks for the answer, it raises a good point and I'm not sure if everyone is aware of it. I wasn't)  
But besides what you mentioned are there any common suggestions on which approach is better (if any) in more abstract terms like good/bad style, or potential code smells?
P.S. sorry for a late reply - I was away with a limited access for the internet for some time.

Comment: @Nick It depends on what you further like to do with the `BeanFactory`. In the class you provide above, the field is never used! If you need the field only to check if there is an `BeanFactory`-Instance in the context, you better use `@DependsOn(BeanFactory.class)` as a class-annotation (near `@Configuration`). Do the code you provided smells? A little!

Comment: See, i had a situation we had a static-configuration-part implemented as a AppConfig-Java-Class, and a XML-Config-part placed somewhere on the filesystem. So we had two `BeanFactory`s and the XML-Config was scanned every 10 seconds for modifications. If there was modifications in the XML-Config and the file was well-formed, the complete context has been shutdown and restarted again. This worked pretty good.

Comment: it's a huge config class initializing beans in a couple dozens of methods. Each initialized bean needs some other beans, different ones for almost each method, and often it's like 5-6 bean dependencies. So it was decided to use the factory to not to bloat the the config even more. So 'beanFactory.getBean("someBean");' is the only usage here.

Comment: @Nick Please add one of this methods(having massive dependencies) to the Question, i think your questions has a xy-problem.